# Pandas - selecting several rows and columns with date as key

Tags: python, pandas

I try to select several specific rows and columns from this dataframe:

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Dividends   Stock Splits
Date                            
2020-07-17  387.95  388.59  383.36  385.31  23046700    0   0
2020-07-20  385.67  394.00  384.25  393.43  22579500    0   0
2020-07-21  396.69  397.00  386.97  388.00  25911500    0   0
2020-07-22  386.77  391.90  386.41  389.09  22215400    0   0
2020-07-23  387.99  388.31  384.25  385.17  4554225 0   0
```

It is possible to select some rows which are following each other with one specific column

```
hist["2020-07-20":"2020-07-22"]["Close"]

Date
2020-07-20    393.43
2020-07-21    388.00
2020-07-22    389.09
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

When i try more columns which are following - i get this error:

```
hist["2020-07-20":"2020-07-22", "Open":"Close"]

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-57b43e76004f> in <module>
----> 1 hist["2020-07-20":"2020-07-22", "Open":"Close"]

c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2644                 )
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
   2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice('2020-07-20', '2020-07-22', None), slice('Open', 'Close', None))' is an invalid key
```

I also tried to select several rows which are NOT following - does not work either

```
hist["2020-07-20","2020-07-22"]["Low"]

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('2020-07-20', '2020-07-22')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-aefccd2025a5> in <module>
----> 1 hist["2020-07-20","2020-07-22"]["Low"]

c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\users\polzi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: ('2020-07-20', '2020-07-22')
```

How can i select several specific rows and columns - which are not following after each other?

Comment: `hist.loc["2020-07-20":"2020-07-22", "Open":"Close"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hist[["Open","High","Low","Close"]]["2020-07-20":"2020-07-22"]
```

will give you a dataframe with the preselected columns.

you can also use :

```
hist[hist.columns[0:4]]["2020-07-20":"2020-07-22"]
```

If the rows are not following, you can use :

```
hist[hist.index.isin(["2020-07-20","2020-07-22"])][hist.columns[0:4]]
```

if both rows and columns are arbitrary, you can use

```
hist[hist.index.isin(["2020-07-20","2020-07-22"])][["Open","Close"]]
```

Comment: Ok this helps a lot

But i get an error with the 3rd statement - something is missing at the end - but it is no ]

And beside that how can i do it when when i want no following rows AND columns - how can i do this?

btw: Pandas seems to be a quite huge and popular module - but i have never seen such a non-intiuitiv logic - sometimes rows are first then columns - sometimes columns first and then rows - sometimes list-form - sometimes sliceform - absolutely confusing to me currently... :=)

Comment: In practice, I would mainly use   hist[ condition ] [ list of columns]  to get read-only values and hist.loc[ condition, column to modify] to edit a dataframe, I admit the first two formulas look unnatural cause they invert columns and rows with respect to what I consider the "natural" order